# sed - Ignore pattern and -i option

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to use

however the lines starting with "#" are not ignored. I want to ignore the lines starting with "#" and make permanent changes to my file with "|" delimiter.
Any ideas how can i fix this or make this in one command?

Answer (score 3):

You are passing the filename argument to the second `sed` and hence it would ignore the input coming in through the pipe.  You can combine both statements with a `;` inside `sed` expression:

```
sed -i "/^#/d;/$id/{s/[^|]*/$value/$column}" "$myfile"
```

As an aside, it is always better to enclose your variables in double quotes, `"$myfile"` in this case.

Comment: You can also use multiple `-e 'sed-command' -e 'other-command'` options, or use `-f script.sed` where `script.sed` is a file containing the `sed` commands to be executed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't want to delete the lines starting with "#", just skip them.

Comment: @BeginnerProg: So replace the `/^#/d` with `/^#/n`.  Your original code deleted them; it was not unreasonable to delete them in the answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler but with /^#/n , the field starts with # it will not be saved to the file..I want to completely ignore it

Comment: @BeginnerProg: waddya mean?  Have you experimented with the `n` command?  It copies the current pattern space (input line) to the output and starts over with the next line of input.  What does 'completely ignore' mean to you?  There are two options I can think of: (1) you want to eliminate the line so it is never processed again, in which case `d` is appropriate, or (2) you want it copied to the output with no further processing, in which case `n` is appropriate.  What else do you mean?